# Error in mgp25 while using in laravel to post a photo in Instagram

Tags: php, laravel, instagram

When I wanna upload photo using **mgp25** package in laravel to instagram have issue that couldn't swap value to $photoFilename
in : 
\InstagramAPI\Media\Photo\InstagramPhoto($photoFilename);

To be more specific , I do receive an error which responds "the input file does not exist"

Comment: Can you please add code?

Answer (score -1):

```
 try {
            $ig->login($username, $password);
            echo "login ok \n \n \n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Something went wrong: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n \n \n \n";
        }
```

try{
                $img =  public_path($photoFilename);

```
            $photo = new \InstagramAPI\Media\Photo\InstagramPhoto($img);
            $ig->timeline->uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => $captionText]);
            echo "publicar \n \n \n \n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Something went wrong: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n \n \n ";
        }
```